# NSTimer requiring me to add it to a runloop

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, nsrunloop

I am wondering if someone can explain why dispatching back to the main queue and creating a repeating `NSTimer` I am having to add it to RUN LOOP for it too fire? Even when using `performselectorOnMainThread` I still have to add it to a RUN LOOP to get it to fire.

Below is an example of my question:

```
#define queue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define mainqueue dispatch_get_main_queue()

- (void)someMethodBeginCalled
{
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        int x = 0;
        dispatch_async(mainqueue, ^(void){
            if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(complete:)])
                [_delegate complete:nil];
        });
    });
}

- (void)compelete:(id)object
{
    [self startTimer];

    //[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startTimer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)startTimer
{
    NSTimer timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(callsomethingelse) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    //NSDefaultRunLoopMode
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:_busTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}
```

**EDIT:**
I believe I worded this question very poorly. I would like to know **why** `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:_busTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];` is necessary in `startTimer` if I call `someMethodBeginCalled`. If I don't include that line, the timer doesn't fire.

If I call `startTimer` from `viewDidLoad` for example, I can remove the `NSRunLoop` line and the timer will fire every 60 seconds.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could always use this method instead:

`NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(getBusLocation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

This will save you a line, as it will add it to the run loop automatically.

Comment: This is the normal approach. It is rare to manually add a timer to a runloop. You should generally, however, keep the timer in an ivar so that you can invalidate it when needed.

Comment: Yes, otherwise the object it calls will never be deallocated if you have a repeating timer.

Comment: I edited the question, basically i am asking why cant i use just your line when i initialize it from dispatch_async on the main queue. Without the NSRunLoop line there the timer wont fire.

Comment: AH, I got it now.  I don't know why that is...I have relatively little experience with GCD ^^;

Comment: @borrrden's line should work if you call it on the main queue with dispatch_async(). Can you post the code you believe is not working? Are you sure you're using `scheduledTimer...` (as borrrden does) rather than just `timer...` (as you did originally)?

Comment: wow! i didnt even notice i wasnt using "scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval" major idiot moment. Thanks Borrden/Rob. Answer accepted.

Comment: It should really be `NSTimer *timer`... forgot the asterisk

Comment: @RobNapier calling scheduledTimer on the main queue with dispatch_async() .so no need the runloop.Working awesome.

Answer (score 22):

And here's how to add an `NSTimer` to a runloop:

```
NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runLoop addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: The OP is asking the reason to add a timer into run loop, instead of how to add a timer into run loop.

Answer (score 4):

Because, as the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) say:

> Timers work in conjunction with run loops. To use a timer effectively,
>   you should be aware of how run loops operate—see NSRunLoop and
>   Threading Programming Guide. Note in particular that run loops retain
>   their timers, so you can release a timer after you have added it to a
>   run loop.

It is a design decision that Apple made when they wrote the code for NSTimer (and I'm sure they had good reason to do so) and there is nothing we can do to get around it. Is it really that burdensome?

Comment: To be clear: NSTimers are implemented as a part of the run loop. One of the run loop sources is "are there any pending NSTimers that need to be fired." An NSTimer is just some data that hangs on a runloop. This is a very good thing, because it means that timers do not require threads.

Answer (score 3):

Like @sosborn said, `NSTimer`s depend on `NSRunLoop`s, and since GCD queues create threads that don't have run loops, `NSTimer` doesn't play well with `GCD`.

Check out this other StackOverflow question on the matter: [Is it safe to schedule and invalidate NSTimers on a GCD serial queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653951/is-it-safe-to-schedule-and-invalidate-nstimers-on-a-gcd-serial-queue/14657684#14657684)

To solve that problem, I implemented `MSWeakTimer`: https://github.com/mindsnacks/MSWeakTimer (and had the implementation checked by a libdispatch engineer at the last WWDC!)

Comment: I guess you meant _NSTimer doesn't play well with **GCD queues**_, right?

Comment: Correct! I fixed this.

Answer (score 2):

Timer method won't be called since GCD queues create threads that don't have run loops

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
       NSLog(@"Timer method from GCD main queue");
   }];

});
```

However when dispatched on main queue the timer method will be called as it will get added to main threads run loop.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
       NSLog(@"Timer method from GCD main queue");
   }];

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the timer to the runloop didn't work in my case. I had to create the timer on the main thread. I was doing this thread creation in a MultipeerConnectivity delegate.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.interval  invocation: self.invocation repeats:YES];
    });
```