# NSTimer not being called

Tags: ios5, nstimer, xcode4.3

I am making an app that has a king of "update method" that is responsible for running code continually. I thought of using an `NSTimer` as it has an option to have it repeat indefinitely. I have it load as such:

```
gameTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.01428 target:self selector:@selector(GameUpdate:) userInfo:NULL repeats:true];
```

Where the `GameUpdate:` declaration is like so:

```
-(void)GameUpdate:(NSTimer*)timer;
```

The thing is, the code inside `GameUpdate:` never runs. It used to work in xcode 4.2. Why is this?

Comment: b.t.w., a style suggestion: class method names should always start with lower case letters (e.g. "`gameUpdate:`").  class names are what should start with Capital letters.

Comment: ok, just happens to be a bad habit I have taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your newly created NSTimer object to the run loop.

([lifted from the answer to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9918172/981049)):  As [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) say:

> Timers work in conjunction with run loops. To use a timer effectively,
>   you should be aware of how run loops operate—see NSRunLoop and
>   Threading Programming Guide. Note in particular that run loops retain
>   their timers, so you can release a timer after you have added it to a
>   run loop.

If you look at the other answers to that related question, you'll see how to create a NSTimer object where it gets automatically added to the run loop.

Comment: Thanks. While there was no need to directly use the NSRunLoop, I saw an answer in the link for the question you provided. It had to be a scheduled Timer instead of just a timer.