# Is it safe to schedule and invalidate NSTimers on a GCD serial queue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, grand-central-dispatch, core-foundation

What's the right way to do this? The `NSTimer` documentation says this:

> **Special Considerations**
>
> You must send this message from the thread on
>   which the timer was installed. If you send this message from another
>   thread, the input source associated with the timer may not be removed
>   from its run loop, which could prevent the thread from exiting
>   properly.

Since `GCD` doesn't assure you that a serial queue will always run blocks on the same thread, what's the right way to ensure that you schedule and invalidate an `NSTimer` on the same thread?

**EDIT:**

Following the advise of the answer below, I created **`MSWeakTimer`** (https://github.com/mindsnacks/MSWeakTimer) which is a custom timer implementation using `GCD` that can be used from any queue.

Comment: +1 for MSWeakTimer... Has solved our terrible memory issues!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should not install an `NSTimer` on an anonymous worker thread managed by GCD.

Use dispatch timer sources with GCD instead of `NSTimer`, c.f. dispatch_source_create(3).

`NSTimer` relies on the current thread's runloop, which is not something that makes sense for a GCD queue. See the WWDC2012 GCD session for more details around GCD and runloop APIs.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I guess the only exception would be the main queue, am I right?

Comment: correct, as long as a process doesn't call dispatch_main(3), the main runloop and the main queue are tied and guaranteed to execute on the main thread.