# scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval not updating timer method while scrolling?

Tags: ios, iphone, nstimer

I have strange issue with timer. timer is updating well within application. i am showing the code.

// Start Timer

```
#pragma mark- Timer
- (void)startTimer
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

// Update Timer

```
- (void)updateTimer:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
    NSLog(@"called"); 
}
```

**Problem:**  I have a textview when i scroll text within the
textview the updateTimer method stops calling and when I stop
scrolling then it starts to update timer.

Now what to do to continue calling the update timer method?

Comment: But can you say where you call startTimer method?

Comment: ButtonClick there is no issue with that. only one time called

Comment: this is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059366/uiscrollview-pauses-nstimer-while-scrolling

Comment: @iMobile yaa its sorry about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For do fix this issue you need to add your `NSTimer` to the `mainRunLoop`. Such like,

```
- (void)startTimer
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}
```

Comment: If you're going to add the timer to the runloop manually (which you need to to fix this problem), you should use timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:, instead of scheduledTimer...

Comment: @iPatel can u explain this answer in simple words why need to use

Comment: @SunnyShah - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918103/nstimer-requiring-me-to-add-it-to-a-runloop

Comment: I think while a UIScrollView (or a derived class thereof) is scrolling, it seems like all the NSTimers that are running get paused until the scroll is finished thats why this happens.

Comment: @rdelmar - Thanks, can you explain me why `timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats` is better for us when we are use of `NSRunLoop`.

Comment: @rdelmar please add the full answer above line is not working

Comment: @iPatel, because scheduledTimer automatically adds the timer to the runloop in the default mode. You then add it to the runloop in common mode. I don't know whether that adds it twice or not, but the only reason to use the scheduledTimer version is to get the automatic adding to the runloop -- if its adding it in the wrong mode for your use, why use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way also,

```
 NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 
                                                             target:self 
                                                           selector:@selector(updateTimer:) 
                                                           userInfo:nil 
                                                            repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer 
                             forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Comment: whats the difference between your and @iPatel answer

Comment: currentRunLoop  returns the NSRunLoop object for the current thread.

mainRunLoop  returns the run loop of the main thread.

Comment: thats not clear for me. what's the best to use NSRunLoop or currentRunLoop. please explain in some words.